# ActiveRecord changes in Rails Upgrade from 4.2.5.1 to 4.2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-2.3

I upgraded Rails from 4.2.5.1 to 4.2.7.1 and now some of my tests are failing because of an active record change:

```
  2) HotelShell all room types have default and english description
 Failure/Error: @hotel_shell.save!

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: %%Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid, %Room types %is invalid
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/mshazad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
 # ./spec/factories/complete_factory_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Does anyone know what changed between the two versions of ActiveRecord and what I need to change in my code to comply with this?

I had some other tests failing because of the upgrade but the problem was fixed by specifying the older version for those gems. Unfortunately, I can't do this for ActiveRecord becuase of this vulnerability:

```
SQL Injection   General Rails 4.2.5.1 contains a SQL injection vulnerability (CVE-2016-6317). Upgrade to 4.2.7.1 near line 234  High
```

Comment: Would be helpful to know what your spec and the related parts (factory, app) does. Btw: Did you only update Rails or other gems too? Are you sure that this is an ActiveRecord issue and not related to any other gem? How did you check that?

Comment: [Here are the changes made](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.7.1/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md) Not sure what your issue might be in this case

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky. I already had a look at that and couldn't really pinpoint any change that would cause this error. Will have a look again though...

Comment: @spickermann actually you make a good point that I overlooked. I did update a lot of gems by running bundle update and most gems in my Gemfile were not locked to a specific version. This could in fact be an issue and I will try by downgrading them. To answer your other question, I think this is an active Record issue because of the error message we see but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty sure this problem is caused by the rails update or one of it's dependencies e.g. ActiveRecord. I downgraded almost every other gem in my gemfile and the issue was not resolved. Other issues (failing tests) were resolved by downgrading gems, but over there it was pretty clear which gem was causing the problem.